Issue when using routerLinkActive in parent route with dynamically generated child route
I have the following parent route

@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule],
  templateUrl: './layout.component.html',
  styleUrl: './layout.component.css',
  template: `
<ul>
    @for (project of projects; track project.id) {
    <li>
      <a
        class="link"
        [routerLink]="['projects', project.id, project.defaultView]"
        routerLinkActive="active"
        >{{ project.name }}</a
      >
    </li>
    }
  </ul>
`
})
export default class LayoutComponent {
  projects = [
    { id: 1, name: 'My aweosme project', defaultView: 'overview' },
    { id: 2, name: 'App v1.0', defaultView: 'calendar' },
  ];
}


and the following child routes when a parent route is clicked

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule],
  templateUrl: './project.component.html',
  styleUrl: './project.component.css',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="link" [routerLink]="['overview']" routerLinkActive="active"
          >Overview</a
        >
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="link" [routerLink]="['calendar']" routerLinkActive="active"
          >Calendar</a
        >
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="link" [routerLink]="['settings']" routerLinkActive="active"
          >Settings</a
        >
      </li>
    </ul>
    
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
export default class ProjectComponent implements OnInit {
  projectId!: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.pipe(tap(({ id }) => (this.projectId = id))).subscribe();
  }
}


When I navigate from parent its going to the correct default child route
for example when i click My aweosme project link its taking me to child route overview page and its adding the active class on my parent.
Now when I manually click on child links calendar link the active class from the parent link gets removed.
How should I preserve the active class on the parent keeping the defaultView navigation to the child route intact [routerLink]="['projects', project.id, project.defaultView]"
A minimal reproduction of my issue is shown here
Default navigation working

Child navigation removing the active class from parent


I have tried to solve this issue in an hacky way based on partial matches (i.e., if the current route contains a specific path) using custom active class instead of the default routerLinkActive

@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule],
  templateUrl: './layout.component.html',
  styleUrl: './layout.component.css',
  template: `
<ul>
    @for (project of projects; track project.id) {
    <li>
      <a
        class="link"
        [routerLink]="['projects', project.id, project.defaultView]"
        [ngClass]="{'active': isRouteActive(project._id)}"
        >{{ project.name }}</a
      >
    </li>
    }
  </ul>
`
})
export default class LayoutComponent {
  projects = [
    { id: 1, name: 'My aweosme project', defaultView: 'overview' },
    { id: 2, name: 'App v1.0', defaultView: 'calendar' },
  ];

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  isRouteActive(projectId: string): boolean {
    return this.router.url.includes(`projects/${projectId}`);
  }
}


This will check if my path has projects/1 or projects/2 etc on my base url and then add the active class to the corresponding parent links.
I am not sure if this is a correct way forward, but works for the current issue. Hope this is helpful for someone :)
